# Why isn't text-color working in Tailwind css + next.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a Next js project with tailwind. For whatever reason, certain colors work while others don't. For example:

```js
{title ? <div className={`text-2xl mt-2 mb-2 ${title==='Valid Url!' ? 'text-blue-400' : 'text-red-400'}`}>{title}</div> : null}
```

When I run the code and "title" is not null, text-blue-400 actually changes the text color. But when I run it with "title" as null text-red-400 doesn't actually change the text color. it just remains black. It's really odd because if I use text-red-500 it works!!!

this is my tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      width: {
        '92': '23rem',
        '112': '28rem',
        '128': '32rem',
        '160': '40rem',
        '192': '48rem',
        '224': '56rem',
        '256': '64rem',
        '288': '72rem',
        '320': '80rem'
      },
      minWidth: {
        '20': '5rem',
        '400': '400px'
      }
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

here are the imports in _app.js

```
import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css';
import '../styles/globals.css';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
```

and finally this is globals.css

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen,
    Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
}
/*
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}*/

.tooltip {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.has-tooltip:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
  z-index:50;
}
```

If anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it. Idk why this isn't working.

Comment: Does any other class other than `text-color` working properly?

Comment: I think you have some misconfiguration in your `_app.js`, because you `import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'` and `import '../styles/globals.css' at the same time. Please read [this part of the docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs#include-tailwind-in-your-css) carefully.

Comment: Hi hisam, yeah this is the only tailwind related code that is not working properly. I'll try removing globals.css and instead just use css modules directly in components when needed. My globals.css file is super small anyways so not really necessary.

Comment: I removed my globals.css and I still have this issue. has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: I was having the same issue and then I realized that I was not including a directory in the content: [] portion of the tailwind.config.js file. In my case it was './lib/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'

Comment: I was having a similar issue before I discovered that including the `colors` property in the `theme` object in `tailwind.config.js` means you have to specify every color you want to use in the project (you no longer have access to the built-in colors by default). See https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors#using-the-default-colors

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to stop and restart when installing Tilwindcss.

Did you try to stop it and run it again?

---

also, if you don't need the second [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) argument, you can use just
a double "&&"

```
<>
      {title && 
      <div className={`text-2xl mt-2 mb-2 ${title==='Valid Url!' ? 'text-blue-400' : 'text-red-400'}`}>{title}</div> 
      }
</>
```